# Split() and sort() list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I must open a file and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list. When the program completes, sort (Alphabetical order, with priority given to words with initial capitalization) and print the resulting words in python sort() order as shown in the desired output.For the moment my code is incomplete:

```
list=[]
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
try:
    fh=open(fname)
except:
    print('File cannot be opened:',fname)
    quit()
fhand=open(fname)

for line in fhand:
    value=line.rstrip()
    list.append(value)
    list.sort()

    index=list[0].split()

print(index)
```

for the moment mu result is: `['Arise', 'fair', 'sun', 'and', 'kill', 'the', 'envious', 'moon']` - but I want obtain a result like this:

`['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']`

The text of file is:

```
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

I newbie in Python, but in this case I don't found, for the moment, a solution to obtain the result.I definitely need to study more about the various functions split, strip, append, etc.

Comment: Can you please describe your *sorting* logic? [Edit] your question to include it.

Comment: it seems lexicographic collation from ascii code order. For example, all capital letter come before al lowercase.

Comment: I've edited my question with the sorting logic

Comment: Why are you opening the file twice?

Comment: Use a `set` to prevent duplicates, then you don't have to check if the word is already in the list.

Comment: If you have two identical words, one starting with a capital and the other not, do those count as two words or one?

Answer (score 2):

there are several problems:

- don't override `list` builtin, use for example `my_list`
- try/except have an `else` clause that only executes in case of success this allows to **not opening twice** your file
- Finally, you only need to sort your values at the end, not at every loop iteration

Taking in consideration the above you can do something like this

```
my_list = []
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
try:
    fh=open(fname)
except:
    print('File cannot be opened:',fname)
else:
    for line in fh:
        split_line = line.split()
        my_list.extend(split_line)
    my_list.sort()
```

output

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'is', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'sun', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

Comment: you forgot he opened twice the same file

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer does not close the file, and leaves duplicates as well. Try this:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
try:
    with open(fname) as f:
        data = f.read() # read entire file at once as a huge string
except IOError as e:
    print(f"Error opening a file {e}")

my_list = []
for d in data.split():
    my_list.append(d)

#my_list = [d for d in data.split()]

my_list = list(set(my_list))
my_list.sort()
```

output:

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

Explanation:
If you solely use the open() function, you have to close it later, using with statement to open the file will take care of closing for you.
To get rid of duplicates the easiest way is to convert your list to a set, than back to a list.

Comment: In this method the result is how I would, but a question, Is it possibile use append() ? I could read the lists and add each individual value to an empty list, using append() ?

Comment: sure, see edited code. my_list = [d for d in data.split()] this line does the same thing what you can do with the append approach, but on a single line. this is called list comprehension. if you feel you understand better the append approach, that is fine.

Comment: also, please do not hesitate to accept my solution as an answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (use split and add to the list then sort the list):

```
fhand = open(fname)

l = []
for line in fhand.readlines():
    l += line.split()
l.sort()
```